# dictionary with assigned value raises referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a code that is supposed to put items from a dictionary in a list and sort them either after the key or the value. This is the code I came up with:

```
import copy
dict_ip_attempts = {"180.237.210.112": 9, "180.237.210.54": 5,
                     "180.237.210.13": 2, "180.237.210.30": 5}

d=copy.deepcopy(dict_ip_attempts)
ip_adress=[]
for key in dict_ip_attempts:
    var=key.split(".")
    ip_adress.append(int("".join(var)))

ip_adress.sort()

def sortip_adress():
    output=[0]*(len(ip_adress))
    for key in dict_ip_attempts:
        var=key.split(".")
        for i in range(len(ip_adress)):
            if int("".join(var)) == ip_adress[i]:
                output[i]=((key, dict_ip_attempts[key]))
    return output

def sortattempts():
    output=[]
    for key in dict_ip_attempts:
        if dict_ip_attempts[key]==min(dict_ip_attempts.values()):
            output.append((key, dict_ip_attempts[key]))
            dict_ip_attempts.pop(key)
    dict_ip_attempts=copy.deepcoy(d)
    return output

print("The dictionary sorted after the ip_adresses is:", sortip_adress())
print("The dictionary sorted after the attempts is:", sortattempts())
```

The function sortip_adress() works just fine, but the sortattempts() function doesn't. When python reaches line 30 it prints: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_ip_attempts' referenced before assignment

line 30 is this one:

```
for key in dict_ip_attempts:
```

I don't understand why I get this error, since I defined dict_ip_attempts in line 2. Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: Add `global dict_ip_attempts` as a line just under both of your function declarations since it is a global variable

Comment: Also, don't do `dict_ip_attempts.pop(key)` while iterating through `dict_ip_attempts`. This will result in both errors and unexpected results

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Add `global dict_ip_attempts` at the beginning of `sortattempts` function.

Edit:
Basically, what you try to do is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371691/python-sorted-sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-desc-then-by-key-asc) in a much more pythonic way.

Comment: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: @Christian see my comment to on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add global `dict_ip_attempts` as a line just under both of your function declarations since it is a global variable. Also popping a value from a dictionary in a for key in dictionary loop is a bad idea (as Wondercricket mentioned). It shouldn't be necessary, but if you need to empty the dictionary just do it after the loop is done with `dict_ip_attempts = {}`