# How to print key-value dictionary pairs in specific order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print key-value pairs from a dictionary with the values in descending numerical order.  The catch is that where more than one value is the same, the keys need to be in alphabetical order.

```
d = {'you':2,'hi': 2, 'how': 1, 'are':2}
```

I need to return:

```
are 2
hi 2
you 2
how 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.      
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Sorted: Sorting a dictionary by value (DESC) then by key (ASC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371691/python-sorted-sorting-a-dictionary-by-value-desc-then-by-key-asc)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function. Note we use negative of the 1st item (i.e. value) to indicate descending values, and positive of the 0th item (i.e. key) for ascending keys.

```
d = {'you': 2, 'hi': 2, 'how': 1, 'are': 2}

res = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))

print(res)

{'are': 2, 'hi': 2, 'you': 2, 'how': 1}
```

For printing, iterate via `dict.items`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.